# Nginx redirect to url with /#/url

Tags: nginx

I'm new to using nginx and I'm trying to redirect one url to another.

`https://server.com/#/page.html -> https://server.com/page.html`

The `/#/` comes from using Angular2's router functionality. I decided to change the page to static html because Angular2 loads the entire app at start up and it's unnecessary for this single page of information to be presented as such.

My attempts at solving the problem is as follows. I can redirect from `/anotherpage -> /page.html` but `/#/anotherpage -> /page.html` loads the Angular2 app and tries to route to the non existent route.

Using this config and location directives:

```
server {
   listen      8001;
    server_name server.com;
    ...
    #SSL Things
    ...
    root /to/root/folder/public;
    #Redirects:
    location = /anotherpage {
        rewrite ^/.* https://$server_name/page.html;
    }
    #Does not redirect:
    location = /#/anotherpage {
        rewrite ^/.* https://$server_name/page.html;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on best practices are welcome as well.

Comment: There is many answers to this. You can't because browsers never send hash part to server, so your nginx will always see request to `/`

Comment: Thanks I did not know that. To elaborate if I have `/folder/#/loremipsum` is only `/folder/` then sent to the server? Sorry I messed up the edit.

Comment: I don't see any location that matches `/`. You location `location = /#/anotherpage` actually matches `example.com/%23/anotherpage`

Comment: Yes `example.com/%23/anotherpage` does indeed match. The Angular2 app loads everything in advance and then changes the views based on data not sent to the server and so my links should be changed client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser does not send any information after a `#` is encountered.

Thus when sending `https://server.com/#/page.html` only `https://server.com/` is seen by nginx.

Thus redirecting is not possible and changing the client side application is the only option.