# Nginx proxy_pass rule is not working for my angular applications

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, proxypass

The following are the proxy_pass rules created in my Nginx server for pointing to two applications. The proxy rule is working for the default URL but I'm not able to point the application running in port 2000.
Please help me in finding the root cause. Is this due to the # present in the URL?

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    location /#/login {
        proxy_pass http://3.81.197.217:2000;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://3.81.197.217;
    }
}
```

### More Details

1. http://3.81.197.217:2000 is an angular application running in port 2000
2. http://3.81.197.217 is another application running in port 80 in the same box.

Both these applications are built with Angular and has # in the URL

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is using difference subdomains because both apps have many routes so your solution will do many conflicts.

The issue in `/`. try this configuration it will work.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    location /#/login/ {
        proxy_pass http://3.81.197.217:2000/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://3.81.197.217/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. This configuration also working for us.  The location /#/login/ is giving us 404.

Comment: as I see you cant use # in route. look this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36761678/13675289