# NGINX location block looking for url containing a #

Tags: nginx, wildcard, nginx-reverse-proxy

Good afternoon,

I currently have a problem trying to proxy_pass to a url that contains a # sign. I'm assuming it's causing me issues since it's the comment character

the url that works is http://ip:port/remotelogin/#/

and I would like to show up as https://proxy ip/remotelogin/#/

```
 location /remotelogin/#/ {
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_pass "http://ip:port/";
            proxy_set_header Host              $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
       }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx redirect to url with /#/url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688891/nginx-redirect-to-url-with-url)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `/remotelogin/#/` with `/remotelogin/`.

Comment: Switching the location URL to /remotelogin/ didn't work. received a 404

Comment: What URL did you try?

Comment: Try to either append a slash at the end of your test URL or remove the trailing slash from the `location`.